# Many DLLs missing when installing composer (windows)

Tags: php, windows, apache, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on my computer but I get many errors about missing some DLLs. I've downloaded some of them but I cannot find any website, where to download *libsybcomn64.dll*. However, I don't think downloading each DLL from internet is a good solution.

I'm using Windows 7 x64 and have Apache 2 and PHP 5.6.9 installed - simple PHP works.

Comment: Paste the list of  missing dlls in your question. Such list can help identify install problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it myself.

And I'm really stupid. Problem was that when installing PHP I uncommented **all** extensions in php.ini - I thought the more there is, better. So I reset that whole file and uncommented only the necessary - *php_pdo_mysql.dll* and *php_openssl.dll*. Now it works.

Hope this will be helpful for someone...

Comment: my composer installation was complaining about missing imagick and CORE_RL_wand_.dll although the files were there and imagick worked for me, so after I found this I just commented extension=php_imagick.dll in php.ini and suddenly composer installed just fine